# iPhone app developed in Xcode 5.1.1 what minimum version it will work on

Tags: ios, xcode5

I have developed an app on Xcode 5.1.1 with minimum version of iOS set as 7.1. I am getting ready to submit this app to apple. But i can only set minimum version up to 6.0. My question is will my app work for someone with iOS verion 4.0 when they download it from app store?

Comment: Xcode 5.2 isn't available. What version do you really mean?

Comment: rmaddy- Sorry its 5.1.1

Comment: What is the "iOS Deployment Target" set to? That determines how far back you support.

Comment: @rmaddy - Target is set to min. version

Comment: Xcode only shows back as far as 6.0 however I'm sure you can type in the version you want to deploy to. But also remember Applications including an arm64 slice are not compatible with versions of iOS prior to 5.1.1 and you must support 64bit so I'm guessing iOS 5.1.1 is as far back as you can go with the intention of submitting the binary to Apple for review.

Comment: @Bamsworld - So it will not work for anything less than 5.1.1 right? You think i can have problem with apple if i put 5.1.1?

Comment: You can select a Deployment Target back to 4.3 with Xcode 5.

Comment: @rmaddy - But i have already developed in Xcode 5.1.1 how difficult it be to move it to Xcode 5 now?

Comment: I meant Xcode 5.x (including 5.1.1).

Comment: @rmaddy - But in deployment target lowest version i am seeing is 6.0?

Comment: Select the project and go to the Info tab. Change the "iOS Deployment Target" there.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52804/discussion-between-noviceme-and-rmaddy)

Comment: Note that iOS 5 and earlier have 3% market share, so if you're missing iOS 4 you're not losing too many users. http://9to5mac.com/2014/03/11/ios-7-1-hits-nearly-6-adoption-in-north-america-during-first-24-hours-after-release/

Answer (score 2):

You just need to set the deployment target on the project, but that will not be your problem. You need to develop your app from the beginning using a real device with the minimum target os version installed.

[image]

To target iOS 4.3 you can't use the following:

```
Storyboards      (iOS 5)
AutoLayout       (iOS 6)
Collection Views (iOS 6)
...
```

Apple pegs iOS 7 distribution at 74%, iOS 6 at 22% so 96% of all iOS devices are running iOS 6 or better. Over 700 million iOS devices have been sold. It is really not worth the development effort to target anything less then 6.0 and many would argue to target 7. You need to fully test your app on a device running each os version your target.

Answer (score 0):

I think device with iOS version <= 6.0  cannot download your app from AppStore :)

Comment: So what do i need to do? So everybody can download the app?

Comment: If the minimum version is set to 7.1, then I think you mean anyone running iOS <= 7.0 cannot download the app, not 6.0. @NoviceMe If you want to support anything lower than 7.1, you will need to set your Deployment Target to the earliest version of iOS you are willing to support. Then you will need to retest and possibly fix your app for every version of iOS you are supporting.